# errorlevel in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to terminate the perl script according to the return code from the previous step.
something like

```
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ERROR
```

in batch processing.
i have

```
$PROG = `spu_comp 2>&1 $a 1 1`;
```

i need if this step gives error, program should terminate.
thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Define "this step gives error"? What constitutes an error? When you determine that, you will know how to detect it.

Answer (score 4):

Immediately after the line where you assign to `$PROG`, add this line:

```
($? >> 8) and die "spu_comp exited with non-zero return value";
```

Comment: very tempting to post an answer that's just `$?` :)

Comment: Then `spu_comp` is exiting with a return value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -le'`sh -c "exit 0"`;($?>>8) and die "exited with non-zero: ", ($?>>8)'
$ perl -le'`sh -c "exit 1"`;($?>>8) and die "exited with non-zero: ", ($?>>8)'
exited with non-zero: 1 at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

**It appears that ERRORLEVEL is not a true exit code to perl.**

i have the same issue. A bat file of

```
@Echo OFF
echo setting error level 1
EXIT /B 1
```

With a perl file of

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$command = `C:\foo.bat`;
print "Error Level: " .$? ."\n";
print "Command: " . $command . "\n";
```

Yields output of

```
Error Level: 0
Command:
```

A perl file of

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $command = `dir`;#try both dir and dri to test real exit codes against batch exit codes
print "Error Level: " .$? ."\n";
print "Command: " . $command . "\n";
```

will yield

```
C:\>back.pl
'dri' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error Level: 256
Command:

C:\>back.pl
Error Level: 0
Command:  Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8068-BE74

 Directory of C:\

12/13/2010  11:02 AM                 7 8
06/02/2010  01:13 PM                 0 AUTOEXEC.BAT
06/04/2010  01:00 PM    <DIR>          AutoSGN
12/13/2010  12:03 PM               111 back.pl
06/02/2010  01:13 PM                 0 CONFIG.SYS
06/03/2010  07:37 PM    <DIR>          Documents and Settings
12/13/2010  12:01 PM                46 foo.bat
06/04/2010  03:17 PM    <DIR>          HorizonTemp
06/02/2010  02:41 PM    <DIR>          Intel
06/04/2010  02:19 PM    <DIR>          league
06/04/2010  12:31 PM    <DIR>          Perl
12/10/2010  03:28 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
12/08/2010  04:13 PM    <DIR>          Quarantine
12/13/2010  08:14 AM    <DIR>          WINDOWS
               5 File(s)            164 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  18,949,783,552 bytes free


C:\>
```

Comment: It works now, but it works with EXIT /B errorcode on one machine and without /B on the other. and not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct return code from $PROG by adding the following line.

```
my $ret = $?/256   #/
```

or a cleaner way

```
my $ret = $? >> 8;
```

Then compare the $ret with the possible values you can retrieve

```
if ($ret == 0)
{
   # Do something if finished successfully
}
elsif($ret == 1)
{
   error();
}
else
{
   # Return something else that was nor 0 nor 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @husker's answer, it's worth noting `$?` only works for codes of 255 or less. Windows [error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) typically exceed this. The [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple) module, however, provides methods like `capture()` that can correctly retrieve codes > 255.

e.g.

```
use Test::More;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);
my $modeTest = capture(EXIT_ANY, "some command that sets error code 5020");
is( $EXITVAL , 5020, "Expect error code 5020" );
```